# Windows 10 x64 does not recognize driver sign

Tags: driver, code-signing

I have rebuilt an opensource windwows driver. Than, I have signed it, but not myself, because in our company there is a web app for code signing. There is a digital signature in file, but windows 10 64 bit says that driver is unsigned. What may be wrong? Why can`t I use the driver without test mode ON?
File is here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qYDieeAePgdIwbDhAHCQxOukHfkujZ0e

Answer (score 0):

The signature must be from a trusted provider. You should add your certificate as a trusted root of the device.

Update. For kernel-mode drivers you must enable test signing mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option